# Send attachment and inline image in phpmailer every 5 minute

Tags: json, curl, cron, phpmailer

I need to visit a site: https://c.xkcd.com/random/comic/ and use JSON API for details.

Example JSON:

```
{"month": "2", "num": 64, "link": "", "year": "2006", "news": "", "safe_title": "Solar Plexus", "transcript": "[[Hat guy and man standing there talking]]\nHat guy: Asolarplexussayswhat?\nMan: What?\n[[They continue to stand there]]\n[[They continue to stand there]]\n[[Hat guy punches the man in the chest]]\n{{alt: It hurts to be hit there, you know}}", "alt": "It hurts to be hit there, you know", **"img": "https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/solar_plexus.jpg"**, "title": "Solar Plexus", "day": "15"}
```

I need to extract the image (img) and send it as an attachment and an inline content using phpmailer. I need to do it every 5 mins, each time with a random url.

**https://c.xkcd.com/random/comic/ displays random comic every time it is visited.**

I thought of using curl to download the image but I can't figure out how to do it every 5 min programmatically.

**nb: I can't use any frameworks.**

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't work in PHP but recently I did similar kind of project.

You can use `sleep(seconds)` to get the job done. In your case, simply pass a value of `300` to sleep(); within a loop

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'your_email@gmail.com';
$mail->Password   = '**password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port       = 587;

$mail->setFrom('sent_mail_from@gmail.com', 'Hitik Saini');

//email content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'This is email Subject';
$mail->Body    .= 'A welcoming description.<br>';
$mail->Body    .= '<img src='.$img_src.'> <br>';

//Attachments
$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents($img_src),'img_name.png');

try {
  $mail->send();
  echo 'Message sent';
  sleep(300);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $mail->ErrorInfo;

  //Reset the connection to abort sending this message
  //The loop will continue trying to send mails
  $mail->getSMTPInstance()->reset();
  }

  //Clear all addresses and attachments for the next iteration
  $mail->clearAddresses();
  $mail->clearAttachments();
 }
```

**Replace the img_src with image link from [xkcd.com](https://xkcd.com/)**